# Why were these custom flags declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Well, 2 days ago, a bunch of my flags which have been sitting in the queue for weeks or months were declined, which results in flag ban. Here are the recently declined flags:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259610/profanity-filtering-profanity-dictionaries-scunthorpe-problem-profanity-ge flagged with reason "Please delete this library rec question.". Apart from it being a libary recommendation question, the answers are crap, especially the accepted answer, and **I can't cast delete vote on it, since it is a duplicate target for several question**.
- [How to implement pagination on a custom WP_Query Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595391/how-to-implement-pagination-on-a-custom-wp-query-ajax/29729113#29729113) flagged with reason "Comment to the other answer." with the intention of converting this to comment and rejected. This answer tries to comment on the accepted answer, by specifying the portion of code to be changed.
- [Using wx.CallLater in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851824/using-wx-calllater-in-wxpython/29768036#29768036) flagged as NAA but marked helpful without action, reflagged with "This is at most a comment." but rejected. The answer only states the behavior, not offering a solution.

I remember that there are more stale custom flags before, but I didn't check beyond page 10 - if a moderator can pick them out, I'd include them in this question.

What should I have done in those situations above?

Comment: @Docteur: First question: Not closeable, please read the rest of bullet point. Second and third - Not sure how to reflag them - the bullet is disabled, and I don't have the patience/memory to wait for n days to reflag them (bookmarking them is an option, but you need to remember to check the folder). The 4th and 5th ones are placed under separator, and they are the cases that I could agree with the decline.

Comment: First question is *closed*. Links to that as a duplicate seem nuts if there are any. Perhaps find the alleged duplicates, hack things about a bit, then push at least the first question (and possibly some/all of the duplicates) off a very high cliff onto quite sharp rocks.

Comment: @BillWoodger: Sorry, I derped when I wrote the post. Yes, I couldn't delete it, and the question was already closed when I flagged.

Comment: Only 1 question is duplicated of the first one, you can solve those first ;)

Comment: As a minor correction your "How to implement pagination on a custom WP_Query Ajax" example never received a "not an answer" flag, only your custom one. The "Using wx.CallLater in wxPython" example did receive a "not an answer" flag, but a moderator never saw that. It was marked as helpful and removed from the queue when someone edited that answer (behavior that I think needs to be changed, now that "not an answer" flags feed into community review). I'll let the moderator involved comment on the decline reasons.

Comment: @BradLarson: Thanks, going through the list made me confused. I would also like a different mod's perspective on the matter, if it is any different from what bluefeet has said. (Well, if it's the same, then just upvote his post).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As usual, the problem here boils down to poor communication...

> Apart from it being a libary recommendation question, the answers are crap, especially the accepted answer, and **I can't cast delete vote on it, since it is a duplicate target for several question.**

That point is so important that you made it **bold** here, but couldn't be bothered to mention it in your flag?

[image]

"Be specific and detailed!" the UI demands. But *"Please delete this library rec question."* isn't specific *or* detailed; it's just demanding. What was so urgent about deleting this 6-year-old question? What **specific** problem required moderator intervention? You didn't hesitate to explain that here, but couldn't be bothered to explain it to the moderator you were asking to take action?

Same thing applies to the rest of your flags. You weren't specific, or detailed, you didn't provide the relevant links (*which* other answer?) - you took all the information you had regarding the situation and threw it away in favor of terse, nondescript flag texts.

When you flag, you're asking someone else, someone who probably isn't looking at the situation prior to your flag, to take action on your behalf... So **give them a good reason to do so!** Presumably *something* motivated you to raise a flag - explain what it was! If you can't communicate the reason for flagging, you're wagering that whoever handles the flag will *instantly* see the problem and deal with it - outside of *blatant* spam or abuse, that's rarely a good bet, and is disrespectful of others' time to boot.

Finally, if you don't actually *have* an explanation for why the situation requires moderator intervention... **Then it probably doesn't.** Use the other tools at your disposal to handle the situation yourself.

Answer (score 36):

I was the moderator who processed the flags and declined them. I'll explain why for each one:

Your flag on [Profanity Filtering / Profanity Dictionaries / Scunthorpe Problem / Profanity Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259610/profanity-filtering-profanity-dictionaries-scunthorpe-problem-profanity-ge) was:

> Please delete this library rec question.

Ok, why do we need to delete it?  The community has the ability to do it, so a moderator doesn't need to be involved here.  Now if you included some additional explanation on why a moderator needed to be involved (like it's a dup target), then it's entirely possible that this might not have been declined. Simply asking us to delete a question that you don't like, isn't a reason to flag for a moderator.

You flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729113/426671) with the flag:

> Comment to the other answer.

This isn't a reason to flag for a moderator, that's what Not An Answer flags are for.  Using a custom moderator flag isn't appropriate here.

The final [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29768036/426671) had a custom flag of:

> This is at most a comment.

Again, this is not an appropriate use of moderator time. You should flag it as Not An Answer, downvote and vote to delete (if you have that privilege).

Moderators should only be involved when the community cannot handle something. None of these fell in that category so the flags were declined.

Comment: I believe for the 2nd and 3rd case, even if they are not the right channel, moderator **should *take action* on the flag** - whether to decline or mark helpful is another matter. And in the 3rd case, I did flag with NAA and it did not result in action, so I had to flag with custom reason. I believe the last time someone describes the interface, past flags on the post should be there.

Comment: _even if they are not the right channel, moderator should take action on the flag_ That's where you are wrong. Moderators are the exception handlers, for things the community **cannot** handle. We shouldn't be used as a replacement for voting to close, NAA flags, etc.  We consistently decline flags because people try to use mods for things they can do themselves.

Comment: As for your 3rd item after the NAA was processed, you've got more than enough rep to DV and Vote to Delete the answer, yet it doesn't appear that you attempted to remove that answer yourself.  This wasn't something that immediately needed intervention by a moderator.

Comment: @nhahtdh Because moderators are *busy*?  Their job is to solve the problems that the self-moderation tools we have on here cannot solve for whatever reason.  Yes, a moderator can do anything you can do, and has more power to do it.  No, that doesn't mean when you want to do something but lack the immediate power (because other people upvoted a question, etc) you should call a moderator to do it for you.

Comment: @bluefeet: Even if I did downvote and delete vote it, it won't come up in any queue to be processed. What should I do? Wait until I can flag NAA again? It sounds like a long winded bureaucratic process just to remove crap from the site.

Comment: @nhahtdh Maybe not in a review queue, but it's a visual indicator that something is wrong with the answer.  If we got flags on everything that was disputed from the review queues, we'd never get anything done. Moderators should only be involved in stuff that immediately needs our attention, a bad answer isn't one of those cases.

Answer (score 6):

2 of those declined flags are *custom* flags to close or delete posts.

Those actions don't require moderator intervention, and as such, shouldn't be flagged for. Just close / delete / down- vote and move on.

2 of those declined flags are about "Not an answer" posts. These can be a bit troublesome, they only ever tend to get accepted if the post really shows **no** effort at answering *any* aspect of the question. Arguably, the linked posts do, to some extent, which I'd speculate is the reason they got declined. You should just downvote these posts.

Generally, it comes down to you using custom flags where you should just have used the default options. Those custom flags require moderator interaction. These questions don't need that.

Comment: `I'm not sure why you bothered posting the last flag, since you agree it was incorrect.` I agree it was incorrect, but it was in retrospect.

Comment: So, what's the point in adding it?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear why I put them there.

Comment: You just added a reason why you flagged it, back then. You _know_ that flag was incorrect, so I really don't understand why you are asking why that flag got declined, in this question.

Comment: *I apologize for the confusion*. I will remove it, since it seems that it causes distraction from the main discussion.