# Replying to a moderator who declined my flag

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, bounty, moderation

I almost asked a question  very similar to [How can I find out who declined my flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252858/1064325), but I saw that [Martijn Pieters ♦ commented that there's no way to do that.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252858/how-can-i-find-out-who-declined-my-flag#comment10294_252858)

That said, let me share my experience under that situation.

In my case I tried to flag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29406617/1064325) because [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29881675/1064325) is a duplicate, but in that time, the question had an opened bounty, so the system rejected my flagging.

Making a rapid search I've found a lot of meta questions about that situation and that the correct thing to do is flagging a moderator to handle the duplicated bounty (those example weren't the ones that I've read that day, but may serve as example: [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225908/284991), and [this another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281182/1064325) - please, comment if you disagree with the action I've taken: maybe I should wait for the bounty to end and then vote to close).

Unfortunately, it happened that the bounty ended and after that the moderator declined my flag saying:

> Please use standard close votes or close flags for this instead of
>   flagging for moderators.

Yes, I understand what happened, and I see the motivation for declining the flag. Someway I thought that the moderator would see that I flagged that as a kind of last resort since I wasn't capable of handling it the standard community way on that moment, but this was my fault not to make it clear that the situation was in a bounty, after that I have already flagged it again, but with no success: the question isn't closed as a duplicate even the answerer explicitly saying that he found on another SO question. Well, that's the standard close handling. Let's deal with it.

Anyway, I just wanted to reply to the moderator who declined my flag that it wasn't my intent to add unnecessary work to moderation. I just felt I had to explain what happened.

Comment: Well, did you explicitly mention the bounty? Because moderators don't see it while in the flag-queue...

Comment: @Deduplicator Nope and that information would have been helpful in judging a flag.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's why I said *but this was my fault not to make it clear that the situation was in a bounty*

Comment: @falsarella Everyone gets declined flags, I wouldn't worry about it. Just keep in mind for future flags that you want to give a lot of details.

Comment: @Louis Thanks! I hadn't find that post. Very clarifying!

Comment: @bluefeet Good to hear that, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I just felt I had to explain what happened.

You don't.

- If you had a good reason for flagging that you failed to explain in your first flag, then flag again and **[do better at explaining yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293936/why-were-these-custom-flags-declined/294109#294109)** this time.
- If you *didn't* have a good reason for flagging, then you just wasted a small amount of someone's time - so wasting *more* of their time by replying to the declined flag isn't an improvement; learn from it and *move on*.

Everyone makes mistakes. The flagging system is designed to minimize the cost of mistakes, since a *whole lot of people* can (and do) raise flags every day. Ideally, most of them learn something from declined flags and get better at it over time.

Comment: `You don't.` - that answers my feeling, confirming [bluefeet's words](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294134/replying-to-a-moderator-who-declined-my-flag#comment192704_294134). Thank you! :)